# How to keep a tex file in the history of our winedt forever?

Tags: winedt

How to keep a tex file in the history of winedt forever? I had already experienced this without any problem. But now the (recent) files are not saved in the history of winedt.

Comment: When you write "winedit", are you referring to the software called "winedt"? Please clarify.

Comment: @Mico   Yes I refere to the software

Comment: In the past, allmy tex files were saved in its hstory. But now it is not the case.